# If condition doesn't run but else condition works

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, if-statement

I'm making a login page using firebase. In the error handling part of the authentication when `error != null` works but the `error == null` doesn't go into the console.

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPassword).catch(function(error) {
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;

  if(errorMessage == null){
    console.log('loginsucess');
  }else{
    console.log('error was present');
    //window.alert(errorMessage); 
  }
});
```

*error was present* will print in the console but *loginsucess* doesnt even when there is no error.

Comment: You're inside a catch, so this code will only ever run when there _is_ an error.

Comment: Try printing `error` object before `var errorCode = error.code;` in each case so that you will be able to debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
signInWithEmailAndPassword = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(() => {
        console.log("login sucessfully");
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('hey error: ', error);
      })
};
```

Comment: Can you please add an explanation on what you changed and why?

Comment: You should substitute `You can try this` with an analysis with what went wrong and what you did to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The `catch` would run only if an error was thrown.
Your if block will never run because an error will always exist in a catch function

Try

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPassword)
    .then(() => console.log('loginsuccess'))
    .catch((error) => console.log('something is wrong...'))
```

Comment: At least try to give a bit more information, than the comment that was already posted 5 minutes before.